# 2 fields update difficulties in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following 2 tables:

```
create table Customer
( 
    item_ID int,
    Customer_id int,
    order_id int, 
    Datestamp datetime
)

create table tempTable
(
    item_id int, 
    Customer_id int,
    order_id int
)
```

I want to update `Customer.Customer_ID`, `Customer.order_id` with the values of `tempTable.Customer_ID` and `tempTable.order_id` respectively only when `tempTable.Customer_ID` is not null and `Customer.Customer_ID` is null (same conditions for the second column, i.e when `tempTable.order_ID` is not null and `Customer.order_ID` is null).

I also want to update the date of that update

This is the query I tried:

```
UPDATE Customer
SET 
   Customer_ID = T.Customer_ID,
   order_id = T.order_id,
   DateStamp = GetDate()
FROM    
   tempTable T
INNER JOIN
   Customer C On T.item_ID = C.item_ID
WHERE   
   (T.Customer_ID is not null OR T.order_id is not null)
   AND (C.Customer_ID is null OR C.order_id is null)
```

This query update more row than it should because the clause where is not 100% correct.

For instance, it updates `C.Customer_ID` when `T.order_id` is not null and `C.order_id` is null even if C.Customer_ID is not null

Is there a way to achieve the goal in one query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use ISNULL(),

```
 UPDATE C
    SET    Customer_ID =ISNULL(c.Customer_ID,T.Customer_ID),
           order_id = ISNULL(c.order_id,T.order_id),
           DateStamp = Getdate()
    FROM   tempTable T
           INNER JOIN Customer C
                   ON T.item_ID = C.item_ID 
  WHERE c.Customer_ID IS NULL OR c.order_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
UPDATE  
    Customer
SET    
    Customer_ID = CASE WHEN (C.Customer_ID is null And T.Customer_ID is not null) THEN T.Customer_ID ELSE Customer_ID END,
    order_id = CASE WHEN (C.order_id is null And T.order_id is not null) THEN T.order_id ELSE order_id END,
    DateStamp = GetDate()
FROM   
    tempTable T
    Inner Join Customer C On T.item_ID = C.item_ID
WHERE  
    (C.Customer_ID is null And T.Customer_ID is not null)
    Or   
    (C.order_id is null And T.order_id is not null)
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work because as I said before your query can update C.Customer_id even if it is not null in Custmer table (for instance because the condition C.order_id is null And T.order_id is not null is true)

Comment: Yes you are right. I've corrected the statemebt, please check whether it fits now. Thanks in adv.

Comment: Thanks for reply then. Wish you all the best in New Year 2015 :)

Comment: Happy new year and best wishes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Use `Case Statement`

```
UPDATE C
SET    Customer_ID = CASE
                       WHEN T.Customer_ID IS NOT NULL
                            AND c.Customer_ID IS NULL THEN T.Customer_ID
                       ELSE c.Customer_ID
                     END,
       order_id = CASE
                    WHEN T.order_id IS NOT NULL
                         AND c.order_id IS NULL THEN T.order_id
                    ELSE c.order_id
                  END,
       DateStamp = Getdate()
FROM   tempTable T
       INNER JOIN Customer C
               ON T.item_ID = C.item_ID 
WHERE  T.Customer_ID IS NOT NULL
        OR T.order_id IS NOT NULL
```

If you are using `Sql Server 2012+` use this.

```
UPDATE C
SET    Customer_ID = IIF( T.Customer_ID IS NOT NULL AND c.Customer_ID IS NULL, T.Customer_ID, c.Customer_ID),
       order_id = IIF( T.order_id IS NOT NULL AND c.order_id IS NULL, T.order_id, c.order_id),
       DateStamp = Getdate()
FROM   tempTable T
       INNER JOIN Customer C
               ON T.item_ID = C.item_ID 
WHERE  T.Customer_ID IS NOT NULL
        OR T.order_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. This query works. However I'm not sure that the response time is better than my query. In fact the goal also is to optimse performance of the query

Comment: @user3569267 you can add this in where clause `WHERE  T.Customer_ID IS NOT NULL
   OR T.order_id IS NOT NULL`